# Excel web query providing the incorrect table

Tags: excel, web-scraping, excel-web-query

I am using excel's web query feature for the first time. The site I am using it on is [here](http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/f?t=PIXDX). I put a check mark next to the table `TTM Yield Load etc.`. I click import, but a different table than the one I selected is produced in excel. It's one far down the page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After further reflection, I discovered that it is the dynamic nature of this web site that appears to be causing some trouble. I have opted to use selenium for vba and so far the solution has proven to be effective, yet slow. If anyone out there would like to offer some other avenue to web scraping dynamic pages using vba for excel, I am all ears. Thanks.